# Easy way to find an MVC Web App start route?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio, iis-express

Back in the days of web forms you used to be able to right click a web page in your project, select 'Set as start page' and know with confidence when you started the web app it would automatically navigate to the selected default page. In these new-ish MVC days, with routing and changes to the iisexpress application.config there seem to be a number of different things that will effect what the default URL of a web application is. Is there an easy way of finding it without having to navigate into the Global.asax.cs\Routing\config to try and figure it out?

p.s. I'm aware that after starting a web site from the IDE, hovering over the iisexpress icon in the system tray gives the debug location in iisexpress but it doesn't seem to give the default controller route!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install [RouteDebugger](http://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger/), it will add a section below your page, you will see the matching default route in the bottom of your home page.